# UITableView into UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a problem when I use the *UIViewTable* methods into an **UIView**.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

When I executed the app into the emulator the method **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is never executed... I created a *IBOutlet* to the table and this is the code into the methods:

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [self.tweets count];

}
```

In this method I created a *UITableViewCell* called **TweetCell** (this method is never executed).

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellT";

TweetCell *cell = (TweetCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TweetCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

if ([self.tweets count] != 0) {
    for (SBTVTweets *tweet in self.tweets) {
        cell.username.text = tweet.name;
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

I referencing the **dataSource** and **delegate** with my *Table View* into **.xib** file.

This is the code when I called the class of content the **TableView** and here are **realoadData** because the data to show into the table I getting form a web service.

```
 -(Table *)initWithTweets:(NSArray *)tweets{
self = [self init];
if (self) {
    self.tweets = [tweets copy];
}

[self.table_tweest reloadData];
return self;
}
```

And this is the IBOutlet

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table_tweest;
```

And this is the Log.

```
2014-10-18 20:00:07.368 NuncheeTestsApp[9036:199026] Count 0
2014-10-18 20:00:07.375 NuncheeTestsApp[9036:199026] Count 0
2014-10-18 20:00:13.184 NuncheeTestsApp[9036:199026] Count 20
```

In the Last line the tweets array is populated but the table doesn't show nothing.

In this code I getting the data from web service.

```
   [SBTVNuncheeServices getTwittwithSearchValues:hashtag
                                     retweet:YES
                                    language:@"es"
                                       limit:@20
                                 WithHandler:^(NSArray *tweets){

                                //called to Bundle Tweets.
                                nuncheeTweets = [[Table alloc] initWithTweets:tweets];

                             } OrErrorHandler:^(NSError *err) {
                                   NSLog(@"Error Getting Tweets... %@",err);
                   }];
```

I have any idea.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you checked that self.tweets isn't nil or empty?  Is numberOfRowsInasecfiin called?

Comment: Yes I checked and self.tweets is not empty... and this method is executed.

Comment: Where do you have the log that you show the results for?

Comment: I get the data from a web service... I will update the code.